# How can I make a din A0 Poster for my formula collection

Tags: layout, posters, format

I was wondering how to make a din A0 poster in LaTeX for my formula-collection so that I can make myself a overview of some important formulas for analysis or linear algebra for example. I had an idea that my poster should look like this:

[image: The sketch of the wanted format]

I tried to use "report" with "a0" or "a0poster" as documentclass but I always got the regular din-a4 page. I also wand to make white boxes around my black page of every formula. I know din A0 is huge so it is okay when the fontsize is smaller than in my preview. Can someone give me an example format for those boxes, the din-a0 format and the black background? I only found some presets for other postertypes but I actually just want this format above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my approach with `beamer` + `beamerposter`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][center]
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=black}
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=white}
\usepackage[size=a0,orientation=portrait,scale=1.5]{beamerposter}

\newcommand{\ff}[1]{
\begin{column}{0.2\textwidth}
\noindent\fbox{\parbox{\textwidth}{#1}}
\end{column}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]{Formulas}\centering

\begin{columns}[T]
\ff{Formula 1:
\[E=mc^2\]
}
\ff{Formula 2:
\[\sqrt{x^2+1}\]
}
\ff{Formula 3:
\[ x^n + y^n = z^n \]
}\ff{
Formula 4:
\[ \int_0^1 x^2 + y^2 \ dx \]
}
\end{columns}

\vspace{2cm}

\begin{columns}[T]
\ff{
Formula 5:
\[ x^{2 \alpha} - 1 = y_{ij} + y_{ij}  \]
}
\ff{Formula 6:
\[ \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^s} 
= \prod_p \frac{1}{1 - p^{-s}} \]
}
\ff{Formula 7:
\[ \int_{a}^{b} x^2 \,dx \]
}
\ff{Formula 8:
\[ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 2^{-n} = 1 \]
}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow thank you so much its really good thank you! :)